# Pandas filtering for multiple patterns and multiple substrings in series using logic | and "but not"

Tags: pandas, contains

I want to use `re` and `contain`: 
A pattern that formed by several patterns using `|` but I would also like to use "But not".

I want to classify types of work.

```
#Data:
v=pd.Series(['New wiring system for an extra room','Build a wall and add a new door',
    'Fix a shelving unit'])
v=v.str.lower()
print(v)
#I construct this pattern:

pattern_cons='ret|wall|ceiling|buil|holes|cons'
pattern_nrg= 'wiring|media|elect'
pattern_plumb='water'
pattern_carp= 'shelving|table|door'

pattern_work=pd.Series([pattern_cons,pattern_nrg,pattern_plumb,
                       pattern_carp])

# Use this code : (I loop this)
for x in range(4):
    pattern=pattern_work
    vector={'pattern': pattern_work[x],'type_work':class_str[x]}   
    print(vector)
    s=v.str.contains(vector['pattern'], flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)
    print(s)
```

I get this output:

```
0    new wiring system for an extra room
1        build a wall and add a new door
2                    fix a shelving unit
dtype: object
{'pattern': 'ret|wall|ceiling|buil|holes|cons', 'type_work': 'cons'}
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
{'pattern': 'wiring|media|elect', 'type_work': 'nrg'}
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
{'pattern': 'water', 'type_work': 'plumb'}
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
{'pattern': 'shelving|table|door', 'type_work': 'carp'}
0    False
1     True  # ------- **** I WANT THIS  "False" **** ------- #
2     True
dtype: bool
```

#### The problem is that the last string is assigned to 2 classes.

`'Build a wall and add a new door'` gets classified as class `cons` and as class `carp`.

But I want the string being `False` for `pattern_carp`.

### Is it possible to use a pattern that excludes `?!buil`. I mean something like this? :

```
`pattern_carp= 'shelving|table|door(?!buil'`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a way to solve it, although not probably the most elegant. **How would you improve this?**, in fact, I'm losing information.

I've added this:

**`v=v.replace**("Build a wall and add a new door", "Build a wall and add a new")`**

So the code is now:

```
v=pd.Series(['New wiring system for an extra room','Build a wall and add a new door',
    'Fix a shelving unit'])
v=v.replace("Build a wall and add a new door", "Build a wall and add a new")
print(v.replace("Build a wall and add a new door", "Build a wall and add a new"))
v=v.str.lower()
print(v)

pattern_cons='ret|wall|ceiling|buil|holes|cons'
pattern_nrg= 'wiring|media|elect'
pattern_plumb='water'
pattern_carp= 'shelving|table|door'
pattern_work=pd.Series([pattern_cons,pattern_nrg,
pattern_plumb, pattern_carp])

# Use this code : (I loop this)
for x in range(4):
    pattern=pattern_work
    vector={'pattern': pattern_work[x],'type_work':class_str[x]}   
    print(vector)
    s=v.str.contains(vector['pattern'], flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True)
    print(s)
```

Now I get the right answer (the one I wanted):

```
0    New wiring system for an extra room
1             Build a wall and add a new
2                    Fix a shelving unit
dtype: object
0    new wiring system for an extra room
1             build a wall and add a new
2                    fix a shelving unit
dtype: object
{'pattern': 'ret|wall|ceiling|buil|holes|cons', 'type_work': 'cons'}
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
{'pattern': 'wiring|media|elect', 'type_work': 'nrg'}
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
{'pattern': 'water', 'type_work': 'plumb'}
0    False
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool
{'pattern': 'shelving|table|door', 'type_work': 'carp'}
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
```